# Where can I find the rules?

Tags: reference, elixir

Many years ago, I bought a game called 'Elixir', in which the players represent wizards trying to obtain the ingredients for the Elixir of Life.

Unfortunately, I've lost the rules, and I can't find any reference to the game or its manufacturers on the Internet.

The main thing I need to know is the table that tells you the result of an attempt to brew a potion, based on the value of gems in the mix, and the die roll you throw.

Comment: This might help determining the manufacturer: https://boardgamegeek.com/geeksearch.php?action=search&objecttype=boardgame&q=elixir

Answer (score 3):

http://www.bombjack.org/commodore/amiga/games/Elixir_of_Life_Manual.pdf

The table is at the bottom of page 2. When brewing, add the cost of your gem(s) to the dice roll. On a 3 or less, the brewing fails and you lose the ingredients. On a 4 or 5, nothing happens but you can attempt to brew again on your next turn. Finally, on a 6+, the potion is successfully brewed.